# gwt + hibernate integration: HSQLDialect class cast exception

Tags: hibernate, gwt

I configured GWT 2.4.0 + Hibernate 4.x

I used Using Data Transfer Objects (DTO) as integration strategy following the GWT tutorial: 
https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/articles/using_gwt_with_hibernate

But when I run the project as Web Application (using Google eclipse plugin), this exception is thrown:

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.net.Socket is a restricted class. Please see the Google  App Engine developer's guide for more details.

The full exception:

```
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.net.Socket is a restricted class. Please see the Google  App Engine developer's guide for more details.
01/04/2012 22:11:39 com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl log
GRAVE: javax.servlet.ServletContext log: Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call
com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.UnexpectedException: Service method 'public abstract java.lang.String web.reg.client.GreetingService.greetServer(java.lang.String) throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException' threw an unexpected exception: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponseForFailure(RPC.java:385)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:588)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:208)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:248)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:35)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:60)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:122)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.BackendServersFilter.doFilter(BackendServersFilter.java:97)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:78)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:363)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:938)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:755)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at web.reg.util.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:17)
    at web.reg.server.GreetingServiceImpl.greetServer(GreetingServiceImpl.java:36)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.invoke(Runtime.java:104)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:569)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.net.Socket is a restricted class. Please see the Google  App Engine developer's guide for more details.
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.reject(Runtime.java:51)
    at org.hsqldb.HsqlSocketFactory.createSocket(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.HSQLClientConnection.openConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.HSQLClientConnection.initConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.HSQLClientConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:173)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcServicesImpl.java:242)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:117)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:159)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:131)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2273)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2269)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1738)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1778)
    at web.reg.util.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:13)
```

I've read in this forum: http://www.mail-archive.com/google-web-toolkit@googlegroups.com/msg44312.html 
that I should uncheck the "Use Google App Engine" Option on eclipse, and also remove the jars of this google app engine references.

Ok I did it.

But when I run the gwt via eclipse plugin, when I launch the application and send some data to be stored on server this exception is thrown:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not instantiate dialect class
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.constructDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:82)
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:64)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:170)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:159)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:131)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2273)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2269)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1738)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1778)
    at web.reg.util.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:13)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect cannot be cast to org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.constructDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:73)
```

My hibernate.cfg.xml is realy using org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect by the property:
org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect

```
the .jar files I'm using are:

on GWT structure:


war/WEB-INF/lib:
|- antlr-2.7.7.jar
|- dom4j-1.6.1.jar
|- gwt-servlet.jar
|- hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.1.Final.jar
|- hibernate-core-4.1.1.Final.jar
|- hibernate-entitymanager-4.1.1.Final.jar
|- hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar
|- hsqldb.jar
|- javassist-3.15.0-GA.jar
|- jboss-logging-3.1.0.GA.jar
|- jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar
|- jsr107cache-1.1.jar
```

What is missing? Or is there something I shouldn't put?

Comment: We got this error trying to upgrade from Hibernate 3.5 to Hibernate 4.x. Never found the solution, so we just upgraded to Hibernate 3.6.9.

Comment: yep, I'm using hibernate 4.x. So you've downgraded it?
I'll try doing the same.
I'll also change the description of the problem.

Comment: Yeah, pretty much instead of going up to 4.x we just went to the last 3.x release which is 3.6.9. It's like HSQLDB is not compatible with hibernate 4.x but I couldn't find any information. What version is hsqldb.jar?

Comment: I deleted the project I was using hibernate 4.x now I don't know the version of HSQLB I was using. I tried with prev Hibernate version, 3.6.10 it worked as you said. I had so much trouble with this integration that I made a tutorial to help other people: If you can, please check if there is something wrong: http://singularityprogramming.wordpress.com/2012/04/06/gwt-2-4-0-hibernate-3-6-10-final/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a Jetty Classloader issue. I didn't get this particular error myself, but the problem is detailed in this [Hibernate Bug Report](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-7084).

Vladimir Konkov's suggestion to change the ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java to pass a null value to the constructor should work to resolve it.

```
this.classClassLoader = new ClassLoader(null) {
        @Override
        protected Class<?> findClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
            for ( ClassLoader loader : classLoadingClassLoaders ) {
                try {
                    return loader.loadClass( name );
                }
                catch (Exception ignore) {
                }
            }
            throw new ClassNotFoundException( "Could not load requested class : " + name );
        }
};
```

Comment: Hmmm... might give this a try. Nice find by the guy that created the bug report. He did some in depth debugging there.

Answer (score 0):

I think @Strelok is right, it seems that you have compatibility problem between the jars HSQLDB and hibernate.4x. If you've downloaded the example of integration gwt+hibernate from google site, it will be better that you check the the version of jar that the example used and also you should check that you've added some jars that is not compatible